# htaccess redirect dynamic urls ?r=

Tags: .htaccess, url, dynamic

I am trying to write a htaccess redirect, but it is not working as I want it to.
this is used to my referral address and they goes to wrong page
i want them when type in the url mysite.com/page?r=([a-zA-Z0-9]) , it redirect to mysite.com/?r=([a-zA-Z0-9])

i want redirect mysite.com/page?r=([a-zA-Z0-9])  to  mysite.com/?r=([a-zA-Z0-9]) ( remove page )

i find many answers but i cant use any of them

([a-zA-Z0-9]) = i mean anything maybe put here

so if you can please help me with htaccess code

i want when visitor type this url in address bar " http://example.com/page?r=b79861i]3gy4792ghindseq34qw " >>>>> change to >>>> http://example.com/?r=b79861i]3gy4792ghindseq34qw

My current htaccess contain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^r=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^page/?$ / [L,NC,R=302]
```

Note that `QUERY_STRING` is automatically forwarded to the target URI.

Comment: Hi, Thank you but it's not work, i want when visitor type this url in address bar " mysite.com/page?r=b79861i]3gy4792ghindseq34qw " >>>>> change to >>>> mysite.com/?r=b79861i]3gy4792ghindseq34qw

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess? Are there more rules? Is .htaccess enabled?

Comment: Yes, it located on example.com/.htaccess ( root ) , my  htaccess nw contain : RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

Comment: If that's the case then place this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line.